# What is the relationship between the classes java.lang.System and java.io.PrintStream?

Tags: java

The classes `java.lang.System` and `java.io.PrintStream` are located in different packages. How does the System class use the `PrintStream` class to declare object 'Out' of type `PrintStream?

Does the `System` class import the  `PrintStream` class to use it?

Comment: The code is open source. Why not look it up?

Comment: i looked out but they are not even related . But somehow System class uses print stream class

Comment: `import java.io.PrintStream;` ... `public static final PrintStream out;` ... in `static` block: `out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out));`

Comment: can you upvote this answer because I can't wait another 6 days to ask another question  ...stack overflow tells me that i didn't ask question properly

Comment: Before asking your next question, please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask].   As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a help forum***, and also not a tutorial or discussion site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `System` imports `java.io.Printstream`. It's a public class, and there's no issue importing it from class in another package.

Comment: where did you find this?

Comment: This is not something you "find", it comes from taking some time to learn the language and how package dependencies work.  One package using classes from another package is just a fundamental aspect of how Java, and many other languages, allow you to build complex software by combining smaller parts.